# Whitelist this email Example-drive-acces@sky-2132.iam.gserviceaccount.com so we can share our google drive files

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-workspace

We would like to share a certain files in google drives in this on a specific emails like this one below

`Example-drive-acces@ocean-2132.iam.gserviceaccount.com so we can share our google drive files`

The goal of whitelist is need to add this address for python automation, on source and destination spreadsheet to be able to copy paste values to bypass report link error.

The problem is there is an error messages
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ncyj.png)

Scenario 1: Creating a shared drive and granting access

"I created a shared drive for my team and gave a team member access with the intention of allowing them to move a file into the shared drive. However, it didn't work as expected. I followed the usual steps of creating the shared drive and granting access, but the team member was unable to move the file. Can someone help me understand why this is happening and provide a solution? Thank you!"

Scenario 2: Incompatible allowlisted domains in Google Drive

2.I go to  [admin.google.com](https://admin.google.com/) > Drive and Docs > Sharing settings > Sharing Options > Allowlisted Domains > Configured allowlisted donmain - edit > add domains this **Example-drive-acces@ocean-2132.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

However, when I tried to save the changes, I received an error message stating  [Incompatible allowlisted domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKyDa.png) This issue is affecting our services.

Could someone please assist me in resolving this problem? Thank you!"